# What is the difference between a chrome extension and a chrome plugin?

Tags: google-chrome

I was just wondering whether there's a difference on a chrome extension and a chrome plugin as I stumbled upon a forum which said that a chrome plugin was simply called extensions.

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815389/what-are-chrome-apps-vs-plugins-vs-extensions-and-how-to-develop-them

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are Chrome apps vs plugins vs extensions and how to develop them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815389/what-are-chrome-apps-vs-plugins-vs-extensions-and-how-to-develop-them)

Answer (score 0):

To answer directly to your question, term Chrome plugin does not exist and what you are referring to is a Chrome extension. There is a difference though between Chrome extensions and Chrome apps but that's a whole other story.