# Difference between plug-in, add-on, snap-in, extension?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, add-on, snap-in

While working with eclipse, Microsoft technologies etc. I have come across many different terms like plug-in, add-on, snap-in, extension, etc.

I want to know what is the exact meaning of each of them? When is one used?

Comment: What does "sclipse, MS technologies" mean - is this question about Eclipse in particular or not? In any case, please see the [developer] extensibility documentation for that *specific* "technology" as the meaning and scope will differ.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041261/what-is-the-difference-between-a-firefox-extension-and-a-firefox-add-on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think they are almost same and basically enhance the existing functionalities of software, However snap in a different one and applies to MS products only

> **plugin**:In computing, a plug-in is a set of software components that
>   adds specific capabilities to a larger software application.
>
> **addon**: addition: a component that is added to something to improve it;
>
> **(Snap-ins)** The Microsoft Management Console (MMC) is a component of
>   Windows 2000 and later Windows NT-based operating systems that
>   provides system administrators and advanced users with a flexible
>   interface through which they may configure and monitor the system

Extension is same a addon but used for Google Chrome Browser while is addon is for Firefox.

Hope that helps.